# google maps javascript api v3 spanish language issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

The official Google Maps API Coverage spreadsheet says spanish language / labels are enabled.

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ah0xU81penP1cDlwZHdzYWkyaERNc0xrWHNvTTA1S1E&gid=1
```

And using google.com/maps, when enabling spanish language, falkland islans are labeled "islas malvinas":

```
https://www.google.com.ar/maps/@-51.5082093,-59.8635691,8z?hl=es
```

but the thing is, when using google maps javascript api v3, this spanish enabled (following the official spreadsheet) does not work, is not enabled:

[fiddle for test](http://jsfiddle.net/vlasvlasvlas/Lm28xhyd)

code:

```
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-51.5082093,-59.8635691)
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
    }

    function loadScript(lang) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
            'callback=initialize';
        if (lang) {
            script.src += '&language=' + lang;
        }

        script.id = "google-maps-script";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;

    function ChangeGoogleMapsLanguage() {

        var lang = document.getElementById('language').value,
            oldScript = document.getElementById("google-maps-script");
        oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);

        delete google.maps;

        loadScript(lang);
    }
```

so the question is:

- why google.com/maps tiles with spanish language enabled does label "islas malvinas", but when i try the same using the api this does not work and its forcing english labels? (though   this DO work using google web maps) ?

Anyone knows why? How can i work this out?

thanks.

Comment: please post the code in your question itself, not just a link to a fiddle.  I did it for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, do you know why it may happen this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spanish isn't equal to argentina, when you load the map via `maps.google.es` you will  see the same label as in other latin-based languages (e.g. french, italian,  german)

https://www.google.es/maps/@-51.5082093,-59.8635691,8z?hl=es

`maps.google.com.ar` loads different tiles(shows different labels, I guess because of political reasons)

There is additionally [`region`-parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Region), but as it seems it doesn't give the desired result.

What works(currently) is to use a custom ImageMapType that loads the same tiles(with the same parameters) that `maps.google.com.ar` loads: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/pwtcjdpp/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/pwtcjdpp/)

Comment: nice one thanks! my intention is to use this way of calling tiles with openlayers, i must use a new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ layer?

Comment: Yes, use `OpenLayers.Layer.OSM` with the 2nd argument set to `https://mts1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=es&gl=AR&src=app&rlbl=1&x=${x}&y=${y}&z=${z}`  (don't forget to set the attribution)